# How to append link to third <li> in third occurence of a class

Tags: jquery

Using jquery I want to **append a link** under the 3rd list item in the third occurrence of the **class** name **bottom-col**.  I figured out how to use eq(#) and I can append.  I just can't get all of it to work together.  So example:

> append list item "keyboard" under the list item "phone" that appears
>   in the 3rd column or 3rd occurrence of class "bottom-col"

Thank you in advance.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 bottom-col">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 bottom-col">
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>grape</li>
    <li>lemon</li>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 bottom-col">
    <li>house</li>
    <li>car</li>
    <li>phone</li>
    <li>laptop</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:eq()` selector for this. It's index is zero-based, so the `div` and `li` you want to target are both `:eq(2)`.

*However* it's worth nothing that your HTML is invalid; you cannot have an `li` as a child of a `div`. You need to wrap all the `li` in `ul`, like this:

```js
$('<li>keyboard</li>').insertAfter('.bottom-col:eq(2) li:eq(2)');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 bottom-col">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 bottom-col">
    <ul>
      <li>apple</li>
      <li>orange</li>
        <li>grape</li>
      <li>lemon</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 bottom-col">
    <ul>
      <li>house</li>
      <li>car</li>
      <li>phone</li>
      <li>laptop</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genius is all I can say.  Thank you so much.  You don't know how many variations of this I had, none of which work.  And yes, you are correct, I put the same together so quickly, I left out the <ul>'s

Comment: No problem, glad to help.